# How many/how much (by weight) orange blossoms do you get from an orange tree?

Tags: flowers, citrus, flowering

An average is fine, and ideally specific to the bitter orange tree. 
I'm trying to understand the economics of cultivating for Neroli oil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a proper answer in a book called "The Complete Technology Book of Essential Oils" by the NIIR Board. Paraphrasing:

You get about 6kg per tree per year for a 10-year old tree
Older trees, about 20kg. Average: 5-10kgs (Southern France).